# Redux: Execute two actions after one another

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

I ran into the following problem:

- I have a button within a React Component that dispatches actionA on click
- actionA invokes reducerFoo which then changes its state
- ...this state change should directly lead to....
- actionB is dispatched which uses part of reducerFoo's state as its payload
- actionB invokes reducerBar which changes its state

So reducerBar is dependent on a state change in reducerFoo.

What would be a clean solution to solve this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using redux-thunk it looks something like this;

```js
export function saveSnipEdit(item) {
  return (dispatch, getState) => {
    dispatch({type: 'SaveSnipEdit', item});
    dispatch({type: 'ApiSetSnipData', data: {data: getState().snipData.allSnips}});
  };
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`redux-saga`](https://redux-saga.github.io/redux-saga/) to dispatch another action based on the results of the previous call/action.